# How can I change a Laravel Nova metric's ending date?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova

By default, all Laravel Nova Metrics end at the current time. For instance, if I wanted to end it a day before so that the metric shows yesterday's results without showing today's, this doesn't appear to be possible. As of now, it will show both days. How can I accomplish showing only yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by extending the trend class and just manually changing the end date to the last completed month rather than current date.